# How do I get the CSRF token from Flask-wtf without jinja?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

All the docs and examples I can find insert the token using "{{ csrf_token() }}". I can't do this because I'm working inside Vue templates (Which don't get parsed by jinja)

My index.html file is parsed by Jinja so I suspect a solution may involve this but I don't know where to start.

Edit: If I put it in index.html with

```
 <p>{{ csrf_token() }} </p>
```

it appears as expected but I'm not sure how to get this into my forms/axios requests

Comment: See http://codeburst.io/passing-configuration-to-vue-js-1b96fa8f959

Comment: Update: Solution from @Attack68 worked however I ended up switching to using a cookie for my token to make api testing easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a basic jinja template that loads the page using Vue.

In my particular case this is how I do it:

## For Dynamic Content:

## index.html

```
{% block content %}
  <div id="vue-container" backend-data="{{ csrf_token() }}"></div>
  <script nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}">
      $('#vue-container').data('backend_current_user', {{ current_user_data | tojson }});
  </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script src="{{ asset_url_for('index.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

(note two methods are used here; an element attribute and JQuery. Actually I use the JQuery method more frequently since it is more flexible with JSON data)

## index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Index from '@/components/Index.vue'

new Vue({
  render: function (h) {
    return h(Index, {
      props: {
        backendData: this.$el.attributes.backendData.value,
        backendCurrentUser: $('#vue-container').data('backend_current_user'),
      }
    })
  }
}).$mount('#vue-container')
```

## index.Vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  props: {
    'backendCurrentUser': Object,
    'backendData': String
  },
...
```

## For Static Content:

Actually for the csrf token I just place it in a script high enough on the page to load first:

## base.html or index.html headers

```
<script type=text/javascript nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}">
   $CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
</script>
```

and then use this inside templates/mixins:

```
  methods: {
    ajax_: function (url, action, formData, cb) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      formData.csrf_token = $CSRF_TOKEN || null
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this I'll test as soon as I'm back on my laptop ^.^